# IQueryable неправильно трактует Linq запрос в MongoDB

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть бд с товарами, делаю вот такое linq query:

```
//норм, вернуло все товары в бд.
var queryable = Repository.GetQueryable();

//норм, вернулись только активные
queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.IsActive == true);

//норм, вернулись только с categoryId = 1234
queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Category.CategoryId = "1234");

//не норм, возвращает даже те, которые меньше чем minPrice.
queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.Price >= minPrice && x.Price <= maxPrice);
```

Что делать? Как правильно запрос на LINQ составить? IQueryable возвращает вот такой запрос в mongo:

```
{aggregate([{ $match : { IsActive : true } }, { $match : { "Price" : { $gte : "10000", $lte : "60000" } } }])}
```

Пытался его в mongoDb Compass вставить, он работает неправильно, возвращает товары с неправильной ценой.

Comment: Какой тип данных в Монге для цены?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, заметил кое что, почему-то как string сохраняет) Хотя в сущности и во всех DTO - decimal. Вообще у меня Price - nullable, может поэтому?

Comment: [Storing decimals values in MongoDB with C#](https://kevsoft.net/2020/07/02/how-to-store-decimal-fields-in-mongodb-with-csharp.html)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо огромное, помогло. А какие еще есть типы способные мне испортить жизнь? Знаю про enum и теперь про decimal.